# Unable to access 'Build Action' property for .cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

[image]i got a problem with my site with my app_code files and a lot of question ive read people say you need to change the proprties of the .cs files to Build Action.

by right clicking the .cs files and press proprties.

but...
when i right clicking the files i cant see any option called proprties so i press F4 and it open a proprties window and i just click on the .cs file and still cant see any option i can change somthing to Build Action.

any idea why i cant see this options?

EDIT:
   my problem is that when i get in the file proprties i have only 2 options...
   thay are called:
   1.Full Name
   2.Full Path

EDIT2:
   here what i see in visual studio 2010 when i try access the protrtie menu/window
   http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/2359/blac.png

Comment: Are you doing this in Visual Studio or in Windows Explorer? (Hint: it won't work in Windows Explorer)

Comment: Are you right-clicking the contents of the file in the code editor, or the file name / icon in the Solution Explorer? Also, are you using VS Express?

Comment: i tried both ways and im using Visual Studio 2010 ultimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Microsoft points out in the article "[Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)":

> ***Web application*** projects use Visual Studio project files (.csproj or
>   .vbproj) to keep track of information about the project. Among other
>   tasks, this makes it possible to specify which files are included in
>   or excluded from the project, and therefore which files are compiled
>   during a build.

---

An answer to a similiar question at CodeProject's forums reveals a hint. Abstract:

> [...] Looks like you are working on a web application that is actually a
>   ***Website*** as per Visual Studio. You would need to create a new ***Web Application***
>   and probably copy over the source files there. [...]

<sub>http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/173637/Setting-Build-Action-for-Files-in-App_Data</sub>

Comment: (my project is a WebSite) how can i covert it to Web Application? i tried moving all the folders from my old WebSite to the new created Web Appliction but nothing apperes in visual studio.... (tried to close and open/refresh but nothing worked).

Comment: +1 - good spot. It's a web site project - i.e. not a real project at all. As suggested - try migrating to a web application project. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx. I wouldn't chose web site project over web application project unless you have a really good reason (and I can't think of a single one!)

Comment: @samy You will have to create a new project, then copy the files into your new solution *through Visual Studio*, so that they will be added to the project. If you just paste them into the folder via Windows Explorer, they won't be added to the solution project.

Comment: @RobLevine it's nice for small websites which requires frequent updates to the HTML. It makes it possible to edit the source directly on the server. I'd say that's bad practice though..

Comment: so i tried the convert and i got a lot of errors now like i have duplicated method or code.. i dont know how to fix them i got alot of them starting from onload methods in every CodeBhind files to veriables error telling me thay exsist some where else and i dont know where. HELP

Comment: @sshow now afther a few hours or playing around reading and stuff the web application work localy but i got some of the problems afther i upload the appliction to a server hmm mybee i just dont know how to publish the Web Appliction can you help me with that?

Comment: @samy What kind of problems? Have you properly set your connection strings and all other environment-specific variables? Post a new question if it's complicated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504314/parser-error-web-appliction-error-afther-i-upload-it-to-the-server#comment12036126_9504314 i did :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:
[image]

Comment: the problem is i dont have this option

Answer (score 1):

You say you haven't got the option being suggested by other posters.

If this is the case, than it is quite possible that your Visual Studio settings are corrupt; this can give rise to all sorts of odd behaviour.

I would suggest you reset your settings, but please be aware you will lose any custom IDE settings that you've previously applied.

Try this:

1. In Visual Studio, go to Tools->Import and Export Settings
2. Choose "Reset All Settings" and click Next
3. Choose to save your current settings if you wish, or select "no" and then click next.
4. Choose the collection of settings( he IDE preset) you want, probably "Visual C# Development Settings"

Visual Studio will now revert all settings. Hopefully this will make the Build Action reappear.

[**EDIT**]
It might be worth trying safe mode too.

To do this, start up a "Visual Studio Command Prompt" from your start menu/programs list in Windows, and start Visual Studio with

```
devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

Does this make the options appear?

Comment: i just resert the setting as u suggested and still cant see any diffrents....(i even close visual studio and open it)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what happens when you right-click on a .cs file in the Solution Explorer within the IDE?

Comment: I can't see that - the site is blocked through my work's proxy. Instead of posting a link - try inserting the image into your post like the other posters have done.

Comment: ok - that looks very odd indeed. Have you recently uninstalled any IDE tools (e.g. ReSharper)?

Comment: :(  same thing nothing change.

Comment: see my comment on sshow's answer - he's on the right track I think

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the file from Windows Explorer and paste it in the Solution Explorer. It will replace (or do nothing but incorporating it in the proj file) the file and recognize it as C#.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should see a Property named "Build Action" in the first line of the Property Window. This property should be set to "Compile".

Answer (score 0):

Please select file and right click on it so that you will get following screen

[image]

Than click on the Properties you will get following screen

[image]

You can find build option in as a first option.

Comment: the problem is i dont have this option

Comment: @Samy : Can you please post the screenshot of it?