# What is build action property of a cs file in c#?

Tags: c#

What is different type of build action and how it affect our code
Why would .cs files default Build Action be "Content"? It seems like "Compile" would be more appropriate.

edit: I created a test .cs file (Class) in the App_Code folder for my test and I am using Visual Studio 2015 (fully updated). This is using the default Web Application template (MVC) in Visual Studio.

edit2: I just did another test and the same thing happened. Maybe the cause is the project type I am using (ASP.NET MVC Web Application). It seems like the App_Code folder is the recommended place to put cs files, however, since nothing from this folder can be served to the client. I haven't made any changes to VS2015's configuration or anything like that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2019

your actual question seems to be more like "how to fix VS assigning the wrong build action to source files" and I think you're on the right track with the app_code folder... post the sources of your solution/project so we can attempt to reproduce the problem.

Comment: maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/q/9500186/1132334